# Ruby Watir Iterate through list and find element

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, webautomation

I have an unordered list. 
ul-list

```
------------ li-ola
Ola
Description 
------------ li-james
James
Description
------------ li-jake
Joe
Description
------------
```

All descriptions are embedded in a div using the same id name "description" 
I need to verify that all items in the list has a description. Without knowing how big the list is.

So far i have:

```
bb = @browser.ul(:id => 'ul-list')
bb.lis.each do |li|
  fail unless @browser.div(:class => 'description').exists?
end
```

Fixed my previous error but now the test pass even when there is nothing in the list. :/

Sample HTML

```
<ul id=“ul-list”>
<li id=“li-ola”>
        <div class=“return”>
          <table>
            <tbody>
            <tr class=“info_return”>
              <td class="info_return_label">Brand</td>
              <td class="info_return_value">
              Ola
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="info_return_row">
              <td class="info_return_desc_label">Description</td>
              <td class="info_return_description">
              Test Data
              </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: 1. Could you show example of html file?
2. You are looping li objects, but in your loop you are not using `li` at all, are you sure it is correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "when there is nothing in the list"? Do you mean when there are 0 `li` elements? If so, just add a test to check that the `bb.lis.count` is greater than 0.

Comment: @DiodonHystrix Sample HTML added

Comment: Ok. Which HTML element is the description you want to check?

Comment: <td class="info_return_description"> Test Data </td> but note that some pages have more than 1 item in the list but they all have the same class name

Comment: So you should be checking the value of that elements, not `@browser.div(:class => 'description')`

Comment: `bb.lis.each do |li|
  fail unless li.td(class: 'info_return_description').exists?
end` could you try something like this?

Comment: @DiodonHystrix That did not work.

Answer (score 0):

For your sample html, this code prints `success`. Are you sure it does not work for you?

```
bb = browser.ul(:id => 'ul-list')
bb.lis.each do |li|
  puts 'success' if li.td(:class => 'info_return_description').exists?
end
```